# How can update all the git repositories the next time a user log in?

Tags: repository, lamp, git

I'm working on creating a virtual machine using Ubuntu that is Prebuilt LAMP Stack Development Environment for Drupal. I will love to have few projects  in virtual machine however, after while they are going to be out-date and I want to make sure that all the projects are up-dated. All the projects will be download it by using git.

After I finish the configuring the dev environment I will make a copy of that and upload it. So, the next time the user will open the environment it will automatics check if the repository have change and if does will make a change. This will make my life easier because I will not have too update every time a project get updated it.

So my question is how can update all the git repositories the next time a user log in?

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Save this file in your favorite directory with `fileName.sh` and add that path in your `/etc/rc.local` file at the end before `exit 0`. it will run in every boot or login your system.

if you save this script in your home directory this line would be like this:

```
 sh fileName.sh &
```

The script is as following:

> ```
> !# /bin/bash
> function gitall() {
>     W=`pwd`    # just replace your directory path with pwd
>     for i in $(find . -name .git)
>     do 
>         D=$i
>         D=${D%/*}
>         cd $W/$D
>         pwd
>         git pull
>     done
>     cd $W # ensure we end up on the starting wd
> }
> gitall
> ```

<sub>source:

http://blog.sdbarker.com/pro-tip-recursively-updating-all-git-repositories-in-a-directory/ and https://gist.github.com/gfestari/6424835</sub>